# Matlab Plot - Font Zapf Dingbats Will Not Render

Tags: macos, matlab, fonts, matlab-figure, dingbats

I have a Matlab program where I need to include a plane icon (Zapf Dingbats 40) in the plot. Everytime I run it, it falls back to a system font.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong? This is not the exact code, but illustrates the problem:

```
title(char(40),'fontname','ZapfDingbats','fontsize',50);
```

The resulting plot always displays `(` instead of the Dingbats plane icon `✈`.

I verified that the font is installed and I can type with it on Word.

I am using `Matlab R2013b on Mac OSX 10.9.1`.

EDIT: It prints correctly to a pdf, but does not display correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the 'Wingdings' font for that. The following code

```
text(0.5, 0.5, char(81), 'fontname', 'Wingdings', 'fontsize',50);
```

gives

[image]

The 'ZapfDingbats' font may not be in the `/Library/Font` folder (but 'Wingdings' is), even if `listfonts` tells you that the font is there. Actually, the `listfonts`
 function adds some extra fonts to the list of the available fonts, and I don't get the rational of that.

```
% always add postscipt fonts to the system fonts list.
systemfonts = [fonts;
    {
    'AvantGarde';
    'Bookman';
    'Courier';
    'Helvetica';
    'Helvetica-Narrow';
    'NewCenturySchoolBook';
    'Palatino';
    'Symbol';
    'Times';
    'ZapfChancery';
    'ZapfDingbats';
    }];
```

Comment: This does not seem to print correctly to PDF, but now I know which font to use based on what output I will be using.